# .NET Project reference automatically included in nuget

Tags: .net, nuget

I have following situation.

Solution has projects `Client`, `Contracts`.

`Client` references `Contracts` as project reference.

I'm building Nuget from both projects and integrating it in different solution.
When I reference only *Client* nuget in the other solution it automatically references Contracts nuget.

And I'm wondering - how it's working?

Answer (score 0):

When you pack `Client`, its ProjectReference to `Contracts` is automatically converted to a PackageReference.

Then when you reference the `Client` package from your project, all of its transitive dependencies are also available to your project (which is the default behaviour for NuGet PackageReferences)